# MariaDB - How to add(JOIN) one more column from another table with IF/ELSE

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I've got two tables called `ARTICLE` and `SAVE`.

`ARTICLE` table has entire article data. And `SAVE` table has the relation between `email` and `seq` of `ARTICLE`.

```
ARTICLE
seq email    title content
1   fm@x.y   ya    hah
2   ch@x.y   ho    hihi
3   ch@x.y   yo    hoho

SAVE
seq email    article_seq
3   ch@x.y   1
```

So, if you save the 3rd article with your account(`a@x.y`), `SAVE` table will be changed like...

```
SAVE
seq email    article_seq
3   ch@x.y   1
4   a@x.y    3
```

And I'd like to create(The result of `SELECT`) one more column into ARTICLE call `is_saved`. And I expect this result of `SELECT`:

When I log in as `ch@x.y`

```
RESULT
seq email    title content is_saved
1   fm@x.y   ya    hah     1
2   ch@x.y   ho    hihi    0
3   ch@x.y   yo    hoho    0
```

When I log in as `fm@x.y`

```
RESULT
seq email    title content is_saved
1   fm@x.y   ya    hah     0
2   ch@x.y   ho    hihi    0
3   ch@x.y   yo    hoho    0
```

So, I need to `JOIN` the two tables based on `ARTICLE` and I may need `IF/ELSE` condition. How can I do this?

Comment: Please show what query you tried to get to your goal.

Comment: Can you explain the logic behind your result sets?

Comment: The closer I look at your expected output and your given input, the less it makes sense. :-S

Comment: Since `ch@x.y` saved the article which `seq` is 1.(`SAVE table`) The result of `JOIN` is 1, 0, 0(is_saved). And Since `fm@x.y` doesn't have any save data in `SAVE` table, the result is 0, 0, 0 (is_saved)

Comment: Put another way irrespective of who you log in as you list all articles and if they have been saved flag as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you select all the articles (by a user) and you make a left join on the article seq id. You need a left join to distinct between saved (row exists) and not saved (row does not exist).

```
SELECT
  *,
  IF(s.is_saved IS NULL, 1, 0) as 'is_saved'
FROM 'ARTICLE' a
LEFT JOIN 'SAVE' s
  ON a.seq = s.article_seq
WHERE a.email = :email
```

It looks like you also have a redundancy as `email` exists in both tables.

Comment: I think `IF(s.is_saved IS NULL, 1, 0)` part should be changed. But `SAVE` table doesn't have `is_saved` column. I need to compare with the current user email with it. How can I do that? I guess I should do ` if( seq in *subquery* 1, 0)`.

Answer (score 2):

You seems want `EXISTS` :

```
select *, (case when exists (select 1 from SAVE s where s.article_seq = a.seq)
                then 1 else 0
           end) as is_saved
from ARTICLE a;
```

Answer (score 2):

A `left join` is a natural way to express this:

```
select a.*,
       (s.seq is not null) as is_saved
from article a left join
     save s
     on a.seq = s.article_seq and
        a.email = s.email;
```

This assumes that a `seq`/`email` combination can appear at most once in `save`.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem with...

```
SELECT *,
  (CASE WHEN EXISTS
    (SELECT 1
      FROM save s
        WHERE a.seq = s.article_seq AND s.email=?)
    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
  AS is_saved
FROM article a;
```

`?` is the login user email. If you may know Node.js or Spring (server side). You may understand what I mean. You use `?` for an unspecific parameter. 
For instance, you don't know which person would log in currently. At this point, you need to use the question mark, so that the right data goes to the SQL.